# ASP.NET AngularJS Application working on localhost but not on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, iis, server

I am programming an **AngularJS** (with Material Angular) Application that communicates with an **API** (I am programming both, frontend and backend (API)). I am programming it with **C#** in **Visual Studio**. When I debug the Application, everything works perfectly fine. But when I deploy it to my **IIS Server**, the frontend (AngularJS) is not working.[image: Everything I can see is the following]

The error in the console says **unpr** (unknown provider).

It does load my scripts. When I look into the script, everything looks fine and the same as when I debug it on localhost (with the little difference, that now everything is in one script but I think that should be like this.
So why do I get this error? The scripts are being loaded, the code is the same as in localhost, etc.

Comment: Does it work if you build in release mode locally?

Comment: I'm assuming you have a 404 error listed in the Network tab.  What path is it going after?  Is the file at that location?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have your api url or port number hardcoded somewhere in your code ?

Comment: @Dave-Bush I was able to see now, that the scripts are being loaded, but all in one file, that confused me. But the Javascript (Angular) code is the same as when i debug it on localhost.

Comment: @Adrien No, there is nothing badly hardcoded